# How to set an environment variable to diffetent values in different instances of same POD?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to have two instances of same POD with an environment variable with different values in them.
How can we acheive this ?

THanks

Comment: When you say _two instances of same POD_ does it mean that your creating them through a `ReplicatSet` or a `Deployment` ?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825522/how-to-set-different-environment-variables-of-deployment-replicas-in-kubernetes I don;t think its possible, it can be done using some logic in your application code.

Comment: Creating the PODs through Deployment

Comment: Please, can you clarify what you want to achieve? You can use two different pod specifications setting different variables to each of them. Both can be based on the same docker image. If that's what you want, please let me know and I'll post some examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set different environment variables of Deployment replicas in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825522/how-to-set-different-environment-variables-of-deployment-replicas-in-kubernetes)

Comment: If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Following these simple rules you increase your own reputation score and at the same time you keep us motivated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using one pod containing 2 different containers.

Here is an example on how to achieve that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox1
    image: busybox:1.28
    env:
    - name: VAR1
      value: "Hello I'm VAR1"
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  - name: busybox2
    image: busybox:1.28
    env:
    - name: VAR2
      value: "VAR2 here"
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
```

We are creating 2 containers, one with `VAR1` and the second with `VAR2`.

```
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -c busybox1 -- env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=busybox
TERM=xterm
VAR1=Hello I'm VAR1
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.31.240.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.31.240.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.31.240.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.31.240.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
HOME=/root
```

```
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -c busybox2 -- env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=busybox
TERM=xterm
VAR2=VAR2 here
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.31.240.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.31.240.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.31.240.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.31.240.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
HOME=/root
```

As you can see, they have the same hostname (inheritance from Pod name) and different variables.