# Is there a way to have a k8s deployment where only one pod has an additional envvar set?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, configuration

I have a k8s deployment - as you know, all pods in a deployments are supposed to be identical.
However, in my specific use case, one of them (it doesn't matter which one) would need to have an additional envvar set - this is to mark the pod as the executor for some jobs that are supposed to be run one at at time, without overlap. If I marked all the pods as executors, this would cause issues because multiple jobs may be run in parallel.

This is the only way in which I can achieve this property without changing the library that executes these jobs - which I don't want to do.

As far as I know, the only why to set an envvar in only one pod would be to either use 2 deployments (1 for the job executor, 1 for the remaining pods) or use a statefulset.

Is there a way to set an envvar in only one pod and keep using a single deployment? My feeling tells me that this is not possible, and I wanted to verify this.

Comment: ok, I realized that my question is a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55825522/how-to-set-different-environment-variables-of-deployment-replicas-in-kubernetes